# MVC 3 and Elmah.MVC 2.1.2, different versions of System.Web.WebPages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I recently installed the Elmah.MVC nuget package, version 2.1.2 on my existing MVC 3 project.  Locally, it runs fine.  Once I uploaded to the site, navigating to my elmah route generates the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It appears Elmah wants System.Web.Webpages Version 2, but MVC 3 uses Version 1.  Is it possible to use both versions?  I fear I need to upgrade my project to MVC 4, which I'd prefer not to do - if it ain't broke, don't fix it.